# How to get non associated items on a HABTM association trough active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have `photos` and `categories` tables and the following models:

---

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
end
```

---

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

---

Now how should be the syntax to the the photos that don't yet belong to a category?

In SQL I'd do:

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT photo_id FROM categories_photos);
```

What would be the rails way to do this using ActiveRecord HABTM in a `Rails 2.3.10` Application

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this. But I would imagine it'll look like this (as a named_scoped) in your Photo model.

```
named_scope :with_no_category, :conditions => ["photos.id NOT IN (SELECT photo_id FROM categories_photos);"]
```

Then you can call `Photo.with_no_category`

Hope it helps.